# Ошибка при выполнении

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

Скрипт:

```
import paramiko
import time
import sys
import getpass

#Функция вывода на экран и в файл
def LogInfo(сhannel):
    output = сhannel.recv(9999)
    print (output.decode('utf-8'))
    print (output.decode('utf-8'), file=open('logfile.log', 'a'))
    print ('\n\n')

#Получаем список IP адресов для подключения

#Способ №1
#FILE = open('IP.txt', 'r')
#DEVICES_IP = FILE.readlines()
#FILE.close()

#Способ №2
with open('IP.txt', 'r') as f:
    DEVICES_IP = f.readlines()

#Параметры доступа к коммутаторам
user = 'admin'
password = '***'

print ("\n\n#### Starting script ####\n")

#Подключаемся к коммутатору
for IP in DEVICES_IP:
    print('Connection to device {}'.format(IP))
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname=IP, username=user, password=password, port=22)

    #Подготовка к вводу команд на коммутатор
    сhannel = ssh.invoke_shell()
    print (сhannel.send_ready())

    #Отправляем команды на коммутатор
    сhannel.send('***')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    LogInfo(сhannel)

#Сообщаем о завершении сессии SSH
print ("\n\n### Ending Script ###\n\n\n")
input('\nPress Enter for quit')
```

Ошибка:

```
====================== RESTART: D:\Desktop\HP Switch.py ======================


#### Starting script ####

Connection to device 10.15.0.204

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Desktop\HP Switch.py", line 37, in <module>
    ssh.connect(hostname=IP, username=user, password=password, port=22)
  File "C:\Users\ruslan.alimov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 340, in connect
    to_try = list(self._families_and_addresses(hostname, port))
  File "C:\Users\ruslan.alimov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 204, in _families_and_addresses
    hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM
  File "C:\Users\ruslan.alimov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Если передать переменную просто как список строк, то всё работает.

```
DEVICES_IP = ['10.15.0.204', '10.15.0.247', '10.15.0.50']
```

Прошу подсказать в чём проблема

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, содержимое файла `IP.txt` и результат `print(DEVICES_IP)` (вставьте это после того, как получили `DEVICES_IP` и скажите, что вывелось)

Comment: @V-Mor  ```====================== RESTART: D:\Desktop\HP Switch.py ======================
['10.15.0.204\n', '10.15.0.247\n', '10.15.0.50']


#### Starting script ####

Connection to device 10.15.0.204```

Comment: В файле IP.txt содержаться 3 айпи адреса. собственно принт их и выводит: ```['10.15.0.204\n', '10.15.0.247\n', '10.15.0.50']```

Comment: Ответил, смотрите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, что примерно возвращает функция `readlines()`:

`['10.15.0.204\n', '10.15.0.247\n', '10.15.0.50']`

Естественно, сокет в недоумении, т.к. символ перевода строки явно не входит в его планы по распознаванию IP-адреса.

Предлагаю так:

```py
import paramiko
import time
import sys
import getpass

#Функция вывода на экран и в файл
def LogInfo(сhannel):
    output = сhannel.recv(9999)
    print (output.decode('utf-8'))
    print (output.decode('utf-8'), file=open('logfile.log', 'a'))
    print ('\n\n')

#Получаем список IP адресов для подключения

#Способ №1
#FILE = open('IP.txt', 'r')
#DEVICES_IP = FILE.readlines()
#FILE.close()

#Способ №2
with open('IP.txt', 'r') as f:
    DEVICES_IP = f.readlines()


#Параметры доступа к коммутаторам
user = 'admin'
password = '***'

print ("\n\n#### Starting script ####\n")

#Подключаемся к коммутатору
for IP in DEVICES_IP:
    if(IP[-1] == '\n')   # Если есть символ перевода строки
        IP = IP[:-1]     # удаляем его
    print('Connection to device {}'.format(IP))
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname=IP, username=user, password=password, port=22)

    #Подготовка к вводу команд на коммутатор
    сhannel = ssh.invoke_shell()
    print (сhannel.send_ready())

    #Отправляем команды на коммутатор
    сhannel.send('***')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    LogInfo(сhannel)

#Сообщаем о завершении сессии SSH
print ("\n\n### Ending Script ###\n\n\n")
input('\nPress Enter for quit')
```

Наивно и просто: в этом коде из каждого IP-адреса удаляется символ перевода строки, который мешает его распознать.

Для чтения файла сразу без переводов строк можно использовать:
`f.read().splitlines()`

Тогда код упростится до такого:

```py
import paramiko
import time
import sys
import getpass

#Функция вывода на экран и в файл
def LogInfo(сhannel):
    output = сhannel.recv(9999)
    print (output.decode('utf-8'))
    print (output.decode('utf-8'), file=open('logfile.log', 'a'))
    print ('\n\n')

#Получаем список IP адресов для подключения

#Способ №1
#FILE = open('IP.txt', 'r')
#DEVICES_IP = FILE.readlines()
#FILE.close()

#Способ №2
with open('IP.txt', 'r') as f:
    DEVICES_IP = f.read().splitlines() # Изменил только одну строку


#Параметры доступа к коммутаторам
user = 'admin'
password = '***'

print ("\n\n#### Starting script ####\n")

#Подключаемся к коммутатору
for IP in DEVICES_IP:
    print('Connection to device {}'.format(IP))
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname=IP, username=user, password=password, port=22)

    #Подготовка к вводу команд на коммутатор
    сhannel = ssh.invoke_shell()
    print (сhannel.send_ready())

    #Отправляем команды на коммутатор
    сhannel.send('***')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    LogInfo(сhannel)

#Сообщаем о завершении сессии SSH
print ("\n\n### Ending Script ###\n\n\n")
input('\nPress Enter for quit')
```

Comment: А как правильно прочитать файл, чтоб содержимое записывалось как отдельные строки, без символа переноса? (кроме Вашего варианта удаления ненужного элемента, за что отдельное спасибо)

Comment: @РусланАлимов Добавил в ответ